# How to have Fn::Join nested inside of Fn::If?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have a bash script that I want to run on my instances but I only want the second portion of the script to run if a value is true. Also, I would prefer to not have the if statement take place in the script.

```
Parameters:
   #TestParameter = TRUE
Resource:
   UserData:  
      Fn::Sub: |
          echo "This is a test example"
          #If TestParameter is true:
          echo "Only is parameter is true"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's better to construct `Sub` the parameter into the script:

```
UserData:
  Fn::Sub: |
    echo "This is a test example"
    if ${TestParameter}; then
        echo "Only is parameter is true"
    fi
```

But since you don't want to have the if inside the script, you'll have to construct the body of the script in the Cloudformation template. Building strings in CFN is always messy. Try something like this:

```
UserData:
  Fn::Join: ["\n", ["echo 'This is a test example'",
                     ['Fn::If': [!Equals [!Ref TestParameter, "true"], "echo 'Parameter is true'", ""]]]]
```